# Suddently can't access a specific server on the internet

Tags: router, internet, wireless-router

Something weird is going on with my home internet connection (I'm connected via wifi to an Asus RT-AC66U router).

I'm a web developer and the company I work for just got a dedicated server (with Liquidweb) a few days ago, and until today I haven't experienced any problems. Suddenly today I couldn't connect to anything in that server: WHM, cPanel accounts, websites... nothing. Talking to Liquidweb an other people I realized they had access to all of those. I could however access any other websites not in that server (Google, ESPN, etc).

So I restarted my router and voilà, all working again. After a few minutes, however, same problem, I couldn't access anything in the server but I could access any other website. This time, instead of restarting the router, I switched my wifi connection to a secondary router (with a different internet provider), and I had access again to the server. I switch back to my normal router, and I have access to the server too.

Then it happened again, but this time not even restarting (unpluggin and pluggin back) the router works. I can't get to any website of that server! I talked to the server company and they say everything looks fine in their end (they can access those websites like other people in other locations).

I don't know if it's the ISP's fault, the router's fault, the server's fault... any troubleshooting that I can do to determine that? I know it's not my laptop, if I switch to another internet connection (different router) I can connect normally to those websites.

Any ideas what might be going on and how to fix it?

Comment: Contact your ISP.  This level of "not working" means its their fault.

Comment: What does traceroute say? `tracrt servername.com` or `tracert ip.addrerss.here` It should tell you exactly which router is failing to pass on your packets.

Comment: @Ramhound the ISP says that if I have access to other websites then it's not a problem with them, that it's the router

Comment: @DarthAndroid it shows a bunch of addresses from the router to the server and at the end "trace complete"

Comment: @Albert If it reaches the server successfully, but HTTP requests fail, then you do not have a connectivity issue, but rather a firewall issue.

Comment: @DarthAndroid yeah! that's what I just found out. I got an email from the server hosting telling me that my IP had been blocked by accident!!! WTF! Now I have access again :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's an "answer", but the cause of my problem was that my IP had been blocked in the firewall of our own server :/

Anyways the bann has been removed and I got access again!

Comment: Indeed it is an answer. Feel free to accept it by clicking on the checkmark outline beside it. You can include how to use `tracert` too to help future visitors.